# How does the EU Emissions Trading System (ETS) interact with member state ETSs

Tags: european-union, climate-change

I am trying to understand whether an EU member state Emissions Trading System (ETS) would compound on top of the broader EU ETS or whether they are mutually exclusive. For example, does a German plant bid and receive a certification to emit carbon from both the EU ETS and the German ETS?

Comment: What's an ETS?  A web search turned up several companies called ETS, but that doesn't appear to have anything to do with this question.

Comment: @phoog ETS = Emission Trading Scheme

Comment: @phoog https://ec.europa.eu/clima/eu-action/eu-emissions-trading-system-eu-ets_en